# How does a stock price chart compare to a performance chart?

Tags: stocks, etf, stock-analysis

I'm new to stocks, and trying to determine the historic behaviour of a particular ETF. However, I find that the stock price chart viewable on my investing site and the stock performance listed in the ETF report tell different stories.

I think the reason for this is because I'm misunderstanding the exact nature of the two charts.

For [CBO:TSX](http://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=cbo), this is the stock price chart:

[image: CBO:TSX stock price chart]

And this is the performance chart from the analysis report:

[image: CBO:TSX performance chart]

For someone who doesn't understand how these charts work, this can be a little confusing. The stock price appears to go *down*, looking like the ETF has done worse and is worth less than it previously was. However, the $10,000 initial investment has clearly grown in the performance chart.

My intuition is that the stock price varies downward because:

- Dividend payouts affect the stock price negatively
- They have increased the number of shares available, reducing the stock price

My intuition is that the performance chart is high because:

- The $10,000 initial investment assumes the dividends are reinvested

How correct is my line of thinking? If a person is looking to make an investment based on the historical behaviour, isn't the stock price chart almost useless when looking at the long run then? Should I mostly be looking at the performance chart for long term investments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is largely correct. The performance chart shows the results of reivesting all dividends and capital gains distributions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Are you able to elaborate a bit more on what you mean by 'largely' correct? What sections am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The fund price represents the price of the underlying holdings. In a bond fund that has much more to do with interest rate changes than with paid out dividends. And, you left out capital gains distributions.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So to be clear, similar reasoning would apply to non-bond price charts as well. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the meaning of the price chart and the performance chart are the same for both stock funds and bond funds.